# UI freezes while items are added to ListView Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to update the UI *while* I am loading things, and I've read and been told that the `BackgroundWorker` is the right "tool" for the job in a Windows Forms desktop app.

So now I'm wondering why my UI freezes while the `ListView` `Control` updates as each items are added to it.

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (library.Songs != null)
    {
        loader.Enabled = true;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int songCount = 0;
    foreach (Song song in library.Songs)
    {
        songs.Add(song);
        worker.ReportProgress(songCount++);
    }
}

private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    list.Items.Add(songs[e.ProgressPercentage].Artist.Name);
    list.Update(); // This line is not the culprit. Removing it has no affect on the freezing.
    loader.Enabled = false;
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Hooray.
}
```

---

Why is my UI freezing up and how do I stop it? I thought the whole point of using the BackgroundWorker was so that the bloody UI doesn't freeze-up while we're doing stuff?!

*Update:*

I have a theory that this is happening because there are many files being loaded and thus there are too many calls to `ReportProgress(song)` happening and so the UI updates are being left behind in the queue waiting for the Progress calls to finish.

So, if that's the case, how can I split it all up so that it processes maybe a certain percentage of songs at a time?

*Update:*

Form1.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

    namespace Play
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
            public static List<Song> songs = new List<Song>();

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            public void TestPlay()
            {
                list.BeginUpdate();

                var itemsToAdd = library.Songs
                            .Select(x => new ListViewItem(x.Artist.Name))
                            .ToArray();

                list.Items.AddRange(itemsToAdd);

                list.EndUpdate();
            }

            private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                TestPlay();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is `songs` ? Just a collection? If so, you don't need a `BackgroundWorker`. It just adds noise. You can just loop `library.Songs` and add it in UI thread itself.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `songs` is a `SongCollection`, so yeah it's just a Collection. So even if there are say, 5000 songs, adding them to the ListView in the UI thread won't block the thread or freeze anything?

Comment: You misunderstand. It will still "block the thread" and "freeze the GUI". It's just that doing the same thing in a `BackgroundWorker` will *not* help at all. There's no real work being done in the `BackgroundWorker` in your example - `songs.Add` is effectively a NOP in that case - you're still doing all the work on the GUI thread (in `worker_ProgressChanged`).

Comment: 5000 is not a big number. It should be added quickly. Use [BeginUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or `AddRange` method. What is the time consuming operation here? What is `library.Songs` ? If that's also a collection, you're not gaining anything by `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I can't do that actually. I need the UI to be responsive while songs are being added to the list. I just tried your suggestion and the entire app becomes unresponsive while items are being added (without the BackgroundWorker).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` have absolutely no effect on this whatsoever.

Comment: @JasonPezzimenti `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` matters when you call `Items.Add`. You dont see any difference here because you're using `list.Items.AddRange` which internally calls `BeginUpdate` already. I've tried to add `10000` elements to listview. It took only `1.2` seconds in my machine. Try this `var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000)
                .Select(x => "Some text" + x.ToString())
                .Select(x => new ListViewItem(x))
                .ToArray();
            listView2.Items.AddRange(items);` and let me know please.

Comment: I guess `library.Songs` may be lazy to enumerate and it may take time? Or your machine is too slow. But in the end `AddRange` will be helpful for sure.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I can output all 5000 songs to the Console in 2.3 seconds. But adding that many to the ListView is a different story. I have a really fast machine, so not sure why but WinForms controls have always been known to handle large quantities of data very poorly. Everywhere I go online I see people recommending to use BGWorkers or PInvoke or threading to solve this same problem that everybody else seems to have. I'm surprised it's working good for you

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I just tried the code in your last comment here. It's a little faster but only by a second and the whole UI still freezes up and all the controls are "blanked out" (by that I mean they aren't even displayed, there is just white space in their place until the operation has completed)

Answer (score 4):

Your `BackgroundWorker` usage doesn't gains you much(in this context). It is just adds `Song` to the collection and asks UI thread to add the song to `ListView`.

I suggest you to use [ListView.BeginUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `EndUpdate` methods and populate the list in UI thread itself. You can completely throw away that `BackgroundWorker` which adds no value.

Otherwise create and array of items you need to add, then call `ListViewItems.AddRange` which is optimized for adding multiple elements at once.

```
var itemsToAdd = library.Songs
                        .Select(x => new ListViewItem(x.Artist.Name))
                        .ToArray();

listView.Items.AddRange(itemsToAdd);
```

Comment: The entire application not only becomes unresponsive when I do it this way, it also takes longer.

Comment: Did you try with [BeginUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method? If so post the current code.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, however the result is the same. For 307 songs it causes the entire application to become 100% unresponsive (and this also includes controls appearing to be blanked out) for 7 whole seconds. And that's just for 307 songs. Now can you imagine how crap it would be if I actually tried to load all 5000 songs? Come on.

Comment: If you can post the updated code, maybe a small program with your current code which I can run and see the problem? I can look into it. Otherwise it is hard to help anymore.

Comment: sure that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my question to include `Form1.cs` (all the code). It's at the very bottom of the question.

Comment: My last try: You can try using [istView.VirtualMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) It us used for very large data source. But bit hard. There is a sample in msdn. read about it. Thanks. Am on i7 machine so that it runs fast? Not sure. *Your mileage may vary*

Comment: Just for everyone information: Items.AddRange already calls BeginUpdate and EndUpdate, but before exiting re-evaluates sorting based on ListView sorting properties.